# Javascript: dynamically assembling a module via recursive synchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, module

## Content

I have a large module that I am assembling in Javascript, which is problematic because JS currently has poor native module support.

Since my module is large, I personally do not like having one massive file with my module object e.g.

```
var my_module = {
    func_1: function(param) {console.log(param)},
    ...,
    func_n: function(param_1, param_2) {console.log(param_1 - param_2)}
}
```

where `func_n` ends around line number 3000. I would much rather store each of my functions (or several related functions) in separate files. I personally find this easier to manage.

This poses a problem, however, as although one could use synchronous calls to load the functions - the javascript will still be parsed asynchronously (to my understanding). Thus several independent synchronous calls to loading files is insufficient - as the mth file might call something related to the nth file (n < m) which has not yet been parsed causing an error.

Thus the solution *a* solution is apparent: recursively - synchronously - load files in the callback of the previous file.

Consider the code at the bottom of this post.

Now this isn't perfect. It has several assumptions e.g. that each file contains one function and that function is the same as the filename after striping the extension (a() is in a.js; do_something(a, b, c) is in do_something.js). It also doesn't encapsulate private variables. However, this could be worked around by adding a JSON file with these variables. Adding this JSON to the module as module.config and then passing the config object to each of the functions in the module.

In addition this still pollutes the namespace.

## Question

My question is as follows:

what is a native JS way (nor do I not want a library that does this for me - jQuery included) to *load* functions stored across many files into a cohesive module without polluting the namespace, and ensuring that all the files are parsed before any function calls?

## Code to consider (my solution)

Code directory structure:

```
- directory
---- index.html
---- bundle.js
---- test_module/
-------- a.js
-------- b.js
-------- log_num.js
-------- many_parameters.js
```

#### index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

#### bundle.js

```
// Give JS arrays the .empty() function prototype
if (!Array.prototype.empty){
    Array.prototype.empty = function(){
        return this.length == 0;
    };
};

function bundle(module_object, list_of_files, directory="") {
  if (!list_of_files.empty()) {
    var current_file = list_of_files.pop()
    var [function_name, extension] = current_file.split(".")
    var new_script = document.createElement("script")
    document.head.appendChild(new_script)

    new_script.src = directory + current_file

    new_script.onload = function() {
      module_object[function_name] = eval(function_name)
      bundle(module_object, list_of_files, directory)
      /*
      nullify the function in the global namespace as - assumed -  last
      reference to this function garbage collection will remove it. Thus modules
      assembled by this function - bundle(obj, files, dir) - must be called
      FIRST, else one risks overwritting a funciton in the global namespace and
      then deleting it
      */
      eval(function_name + "= undefined")
    }
  }
}

var test_module = {}
bundle(test_module, ["a.js", "b.js", "log_num.js", "many_parameters.js"], "test_module/")
```

#### a.js

```
function a() {
  console.log("a")
}
```

#### b.js

```
function b() {
  console.log("b")
}
```

#### log_num.js

```
// it works with parameters too
function log_num(num) {
  console.log(num)
}
```

#### many_parameters.js

```
function many_parameters(a, b, c) {
  var calc = a - b * c
  console.log(calc)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we restrict our tools to the "native JS way", there is an `import()` proposal, currently at Stage 3 on the TC39 proposal process:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

[*System.js*](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) offers a similar approach to dynamically load modules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). From the home page:

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

It has support for [Definition Functions with Dependencies](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep)

> If the module has dependencies, the first argument should be an array of dependency names, and the second argument should be a definition function. The function will be called to define the module once all dependencies have loaded. The function should return an object that defines the module. The dependencies will be passed to the definition function as function arguments, listed in the same order as the order in the dependency array:

That would allow you to "split up" your module into what ever arbitrary pieces you decide and "assemble" them at load time.

Comment: Yes I have looked at various libraries for solving this problem. Some are in native JS - others less so. However I would prefer a concise  solution to this problem that I understand without having to trace through source code. The function I provide above - `bundle` - is quite basic and consequently understandable.  There should be a concise solution to this problem without the need for an external library.

Comment: I understand your point. There are no well written libraries in javascript that do not use "native JS" (at least not in a browser). The reason that the libraries are written is to solve exactly the problem you are having. "How do I do X, since there is no 'native/built in' way to do X out of the box". After a while some of us just get tired of reinventing the wheel every time. To each his own.